# select all rows with same column to separate columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, mariadb, pivot-table, group-concat

I have a table like this :

```
fkey | sensor | depth | value 
-----+--------+-------+-------
1    | 1      | 1     | 34
1    | 1      | 2     | 27
1    | 2      | 1     | 22
1    | 2      | 2     | 34
1    | 2      | 3     | 56
2    | 1      | 1     | 12
2    | 1      | 2     | 24
2    | 2      | 1     | 56
3    | 1      | 1     | 43
3    | 1      | 2     | 89
3    | 1      | 3     | 97
```

How to write select query to `GROUP_CONCAT` value for each sensor and `ORDER BY` depth to show this?

```
fkey | sensor1_values  |  sensor2_values
-----+-----------------+------------------
1    | 34,27           |  22,34,56 
2    | 12,24           |  56
3    | 43,89,97        |  NULL
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `GROUP_CONCAT` with a `CASE` expression to target each of the sensor data.

```
SELECT
    fkey,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN sensor=1 THEN value END ORDER BY depth) AS sensor1_values,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN sensor=2 THEN value END ORDER BY depth) AS sensor2_values
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY fkey;
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works, but how can I generate column names automatically from it?

Comment: @MojtabaArvin You would need dynamic SQL for that, to generate column names, or to handle an arbitrary number of sensors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, by replacing table name and column name

fkey is column A | sensor is column B | depth is is column C | value is column D

```
select A, STUFF((SELECT ', ' + D FROM tableA b 
           WHERE b.A = a.A AND b.B = 1
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') sensor1_values  
          , STUFF((SELECT ', ' + D FROM tableA b 
           WHERE b.A = a.A AND b.B = 2
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') sensor2_values
from tableA a
group by A
```

Comment: This question was tagged for MySQL, not SQL Server.